# Is it possible to symmetric weight-paint an asymmetric mesh?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

Is it possible to do symmetrical weight painting without manually splitting my mesh into two pieces? I've already done building my mesh. I don't want to split it into two pieces because:

a) My mesh is not symmetrical to start with

b) It's gonna mess up the rigging on other parts

There are certain parts on the mesh that ARE symmetrical which I want to do symmetrical weight painting. What I mean is when I paint on the left side, Blender draws an imaginary line across middle of mesh and the right side will automatically get painted the exact same.

What I mean:

[image]

I want to be able to weight paint left side of that indicated area, then right side will automatically reflect same weight painting. But as you can see even though the upper part is symmetrical, entire object is not symmetrical. No this is not my object I just quickly drew it in MS Paint to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: According to person asking this question, this is the exact opposite of what they wanted, all i can say is just tick it on instead of off, but they said that doesn't work, i shall keep this up for those who find it though.

This is because X Mirroring is on, to turn it off go to into the Weight Painting mode on your desired object.

On the left Toolshelf <kbd>T</kbd> select the Options(1) tab.

Under Options(2) Uncheck the checkbox labeled as "X Mirror"(3)

[image: Main image for the steps]

Your weight painting should be fine now!

Tip: open up a new file, without changing anything (other than what i'm saying now), even moving the camera, repeat the steps above and then with the mouse over 3D view, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then press "Save Startup File"

This makes your blender startup file have what you just did already done, so you don't have to do it again.

Comment: The (T) toolshelf, not the (N) Toolshelf *facepalm*, dont mind me im tripping

Comment: @eromod Don't worry about it. :P

Comment: Not sure if you read my question... I WANT mirroring, I think your answer is the exact opposite. Also turning on X-mirroring did nothing,

Comment: @Heartcloud Oh haha, sorry about that, i did read it, just read it wrong, it was past 3:00 Am. Anyway, not sure what to do, so to have me and others fully understand it, upload the .blend using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and edit your post with the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported, while texture paint and sculpt support symmetrical painting (applying the brush on multiple axis at once), weight paint only supports mirroring weights, which requires each vertex to have a mirrored match.

---

Note that this is possible in to weight paint on asymetrical meshes as long as the topology is symmetrical, using the *Topology Mirror* option.

It does require the models have enough unique topology areas (most character models are fine), but it will fail for a cube or a grid for example.